# /var/log/nginx not present in docker container and directory fail to be created by Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, nginx

In the Dockerfile, there is `RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx` right after the `FROM`, but for some reason it doesn't get created in the container as shown below

```
root@c6d43f610a51:/etc/nginx# cd /var/log
root@c6d43f610a51:/var/log# ls
```

This is the `nginx` configuration on the container. It clearly states that the `nginx` logs are to be present in `/var/log/nginx`, yet this doesn't happen.

```
root@c6d43f610a51:/var/log# cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user  nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
daemon off;
```

This is my complete Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.5
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx
RUN pip install pipenv python-dotenv requests jira  \
        && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
        && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
CMD [ "pipenv", "run","flask", "run"]
```

FYI: the `nginx` webserver is working as expected so there should be logs populating.

Answer (score 1):

The NGINX server process runs as user `nginx` (see the first line in `nginx.conf`).

You run `mkdir` as root so that will be the owner of `/var/log/nginx`.

You need to give write access rights for the user nginx to the folder /var/log/nginx. In the simplest form you can give write access to all users:

```sh
RUN chmod -R a+w /var/log/nginx
```

Comment: good point, but if the directory is already created in the container, why doesnt it show when I do `ls /var/log` ? Actually when I do this, docker-build says RUN not found because it can't see the `/var/log/nginx` in the container.

Comment: For me it does show it. My first guess would be that you are running an old image. Make sure that you use the same image name to build and to run the container.

Comment: yes now it's created, but no nginx logs are inside it even though the webserver is running